# How to join columns in 1 table. One with a column that is being split by a comma

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to see all the results from one table. But one of the columns I am also splitting into two columns with a comma. Here's what it looks like

```
          Table 1
-------------------------
colA,  colB,  colC,  colD
 A     B1,B2    C      D
 A     B1,B2    C      D
```

what I am trying to get is

```
          Table 1
-------------------------
colA,  colB1,  colB2, colC,  colD
 A     B1,       B2     C      D
 A     B1,       B2     C      D
```

I think I have to join or union, but am having trouble.

## I know this splits col B for me

```
SELECT split_part(colB, ',', 1) AS City
     , split_part(colB, ',', 2) AS State
FROM   table1
```

## And I know I want to

```
Select colA, ColC, ColD from table 1
```

Basically I am trying to turn 4 columns into 5. (Column 2 info has a comma in it so I want to split it)

Comment: So just do it! `select colA, split_part(colB, ',', 1) as colB1, split_part(colB, ',', 2) as colB2, colC, colD from table`

Comment: Your question title said there were two tables - where is the second?

Comment: Yea.. initially it was, but I changed it. Sorry Ill fix it

Comment: Wait, what would you do if you wanted to add another table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the answer, so I'll post it here

```
select
    colA,
    split_part(colB, ',', 1) as colB1,
    split_part(colB, ',', 2) as colB2,
    colC,
    colD
from
    table
```